# How do I make the area on the top of a UISearchBar (when on a UITableView) in iOS 7 transparent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Here is a picture describing the problem. Notice that the area above the `UISearchBar` does not have the background as below it. I don't want the gray color, I want the dark maroon background when pulling down on the `UITableView`.

Everything I know of is set to `[UIColor clearColor]`, including backgrounds of views, etc. **It works fine in iOS 6 but not iOS 7!**

I've also attached a sample project so someone can take a look and see what I am doing wrong here?

[Click here to download my sample project](http://www.ethanproductions.com/SearchBarBug.zip)

Maybe I am just missing something stupid?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you could do:  1) add an explicit clear background view to the UITableView.  Or, 2) set your UIImageView to be the background view of the UITableView.

Either of these work.  Here's the code that makes your sample work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Film_bg.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundImageView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImageView];

    // solution 1
//    self.tableView.backgroundView = [UIView new];
//    self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // solution 2
    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundImageView;
}
```